# AT command (ATD) to dial a network service number(**21*<NO>;) on a huawei modem

Tags: at-command

I have a problem dialing a service command ( Ex: ATD**21*#; ) , with a huawei modem , while it works perfectly well with a  teracom modem with same set of AT commands and same SIM card ,

On teracom ,

```
phone_cmd(conn,"ATE0")  
phone_cmd(conn,"AT+CFUN=1")  
phone_cmd(conn,"AT+CMEE=1")  
phone_cmd(conn,"AT+CPIN?")  
phone_cmd(conn,"AT*ECAM=1")  
phone_cmd(conn,"AT*EREG=2")  
phone_cmd(conn,"AT+CLIP=1;+CRC=1")  
phone_cmd(conn,"ATD**21*XXXXXXXXXXXX#;") //works for teracom (LW272)
```

but the same command set, doesn't work on a huawei E173B-u modem,  what am i missing here, can it possibly be some command or is it a hardware limitation ..

Answer (score 0):

For some supplementary services, It is recommended not to use AT commands. But you can enable the supplementary service by "AT" command and then try to use ATD.
For example: +CLIR which suppress BCD in setup message can be activated by At+CLIR=2
After this if you call by ATD.. The called party cannot see calling party's number.
With UI its simple to do the same exercise=> *31#XXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

[27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) states in chapter 6.2:

> 6.2 ITU-T V.250 dial command D
>
> V.250 dial command D lists characters that may be used in a dialling string for making a call or
>   controlling supplementary services in accordance with 3GPP TS 22.030.
>   Their use in GSM/UMTS is listed in this subclause, as well as
>   new dial modifiers applicable only to GSM/UMTS are introduced. For a
>   MT supporting AT commands only, it is mandatory to support the control
>   of supplementary services in accordance with 3GPP TS 22.030
>   through the dial command or through the specific supplementary service
>   commands (+CCFC, +CLCK, etc.), where 3GPP TS 22.030 identifies
>   the supplementary services as mandatory.

So if this huawei modem is a pure modem without an user interface to interact with and send some supplementary services commands though, this is a clear violation of the specification (although not unlikely) (provided 21 is mandatory which I am relatively sure it is).

You might try to use the unstructured supplementary service command `AT+CUSD`. Although USSD is a separate thing from SS, the network might or might not have some mapping/overlap.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use 'at' command which is used to send USSD instead of dialing.